# Only generate one war during package

Tags: maven, war, jhipster

By default JHipster generate 2 wars during the package phase (your_project_version.war & your_project_version.war.original). The first one is the executable jar and the second is the war you can use in a servlet container.

Is there a way to only generate the 'original' war. The executable is not required for my project and I would like to deploy the war to Nexus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jhipster generated project will make use of spring-boot, and in particular of the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html#), which by default binds the `repackage` goal to the `package` lifecycle phase. If you want to disable the repackaging, it should be enough to edit your pomfile, so that no execution is present for the repackage goal (by setting the bound phase to `none`):

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>repackage</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you need so, you will then be able to run the goal directly, as:

```
mvn package spring-boot:repackage
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the fast answer. Exactly what I need.

Comment: This configuration does not work for me, using spring boot 2.7.12. This question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398974/2183717 works.

Answer (score 0):

In SpringBoot 2, removing executions did not work for me. I needed to set goal to package :

```
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <goals>
       <goal>package</goal>
     </goals>
     <phase>none</phase>
  </execution>
</executions>
```